# If-then formular in table QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, table

I am working with QGIS and I have a table with several columns, some of them I defined as drop-down columns. In the next step I would like to define certain specifications. For example: If column A is "positive", then "not funded" must be selected in column B. I am not very familiar with Python, SQL and so on.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Have you had a look at the documentation?

Comment: QGIS has an if function : "if(condition,result_when_true,result_when_false)" or a "CASE" fonction. I suggest you have a look at the attribute form (https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/forms.html?highlight=form#ls-forms) and try to implement your condition there, then to update your question if you get stuck update

Comment: I think OP is asking "If I choose *positive* in col1, only the choice *not funded* should be available to choose from in col2". If you are see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416327/attribute-subdomain-in-qfield